# Как после выполнение условия выполнить редирект на компонент?

Tags: reactjs

Как после выполнение условия выполнить редирект на компонент show

```
if (test == 1){
редирект '/show/'
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: this.props.history.push('/somepage');

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете React Router, то можно так:

```
import {browserHistory} from "react-router";

componentDidMount() {
     if(this.props.test === 1) {
           browserHistory.push("/show");
     }
}
```

Comment: Это надо вставить? 
<Route  exact path={browserHistory}  component={Show} />

Comment: <Route exact path='/show' component={ Show }>

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }
  setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    })
  }
  renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/target' />
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
       <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```